# Is there a way to call getopt($options) multiple times?

Tags: php, command-line, getopt

I'm working on a php script which will redirect and execute some functions depending on the choice of the user.

One can use my script to, say, list all options, use algorithm `A`, use algorithm `B`.

The thing is, `A` may require more parameters than the original script, and `B` may require some other paremeters.

I planned to use `getopt("r:i:")` in the first script, then use
`getopt("u:p:")` in `A` as it requires an `u`sername and a `p`assword, but it seems `getotp` empties the arguments line it is working with on the first time.

So let's imagine I would like to use

```
$ php -f file.php -- -r "path" -i "A" -u "username" -p "password"
```

with `-i "A"` meaning *use algorithm A*

But on the second time i use `getopt`, it returns an empty array.

Is there a way to use it two times, or maybe a way to tell it not to remove inexistent entries ?